# How to remove print suppression - parallel package

Tags: r, parallel-processing

The `parallel` package suppresses non-returned printing with `parSapply` and `parLapply`. Is it possible to bypass this effect?

Normal (with expected behavior)

```
sapply(iris, function(x) {
  print("x")
  message("message")
  warning("warning")
  return(x[2])
})
# [1] "x"
# message
# [1] "x"
# message
# [1] "x"
# message
# [1] "x"
# message
# [1] "x"
# message
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#          4.9          3.0          1.4          0.2          1.0 
# Warning messages:
# 1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : warning
# 2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : warning
# 3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : warning
# 4: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : warning
# 5: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : warning
```

Parallel process (unexpected suppression)

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(3)
parSapply(cl, iris, function(x) {
  print("x")
  message("message")
  warning("warning")
  return(x[2])
})
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#          4.9          3.0          1.4          0.2          1.0

#Run after
stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this it is possible because of [issues with parallel access to R terminal from separate processes forked by `parallel`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35616419/1699652)

If you need to get messages from your processes then [this SO answer should help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16718078/1699652) (Briefly: use `outfile` param in `parallel::makeCluster`)